# How do I get the form to be on the same line as by navigation buttons?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've tried playing with putting the indents and placement in different places but it still appear underneath the navigation button. I want it on the same line across the top. 
I might of made it a bit messy trying to get it on the same line, if so just take out whenever isn't necessary. 
`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bootstrap For Beginners</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Hello World">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<style>
    .nav {

    }
    .nav container-fluid {


    }
    .nav li {
        display: inline;
        padding: 20px;
        font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
    }

    .jumbotron {


    }
    .jumbotron container-fluid {

    }
    .jumbotron h1 {

    .footer {

    }
    .footer container-fluid {

    }
    .footer p {

    }

</style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">About</a></li>
            </ul>

            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Have Feedback?">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit Feedback</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <h1>Student</h1>
                <h1>Business</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <p>By:</p>
            <p>For:</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body> 
</html>
```

The input bar doesn't seem to be responsive on really really small windows, is that normal?

I also want the footer to be the same size as the nav header and the jumbotron to fill up the rest of the space in between, everything fits in the window with no scrolling.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't understand what you are asking, try to recreated it with this.  http://jsfiddle.net/0njg4b8s/

Comment: @wlin Did you even include Bootstrap in the JSFiddle? That would **really** help you understand his question.

Comment: @TimLewis I did on the left side I uploaded the external css.

Comment: @wlin You forgot the Javascript/JQuery. Here's the update: http://jsfiddle.net/0njg4b8s/2/

Comment: so from the nav to the form you want on the same line?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0njg4b8s/3/ like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks great, all you have to do is wrap the form and nav in a wrapper / container then separate the sections with col-md-6. I built an example for you here http://www.bootply.com/P7VmPZOfXp.

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
.footer {
    height: 58px;
    background: #ccc;

  }
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="container-fluid">

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                                <form class="form-horizontal">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Have Feedback?" type="email">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit Feedback</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form><!-- .form-horizontal -->
                    </div><!-- .col-6 -->

                      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                            <div class="nav">
                                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                                    <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                                    <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div><!-- .nav -->
                        </div><!-- .col-6 -->

        </div><!-- .fluid container -->
    </div><!-- .row -->
</div><!-- .container-->
</div><!-- .wrapper-->
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <h1>Student</h1>
                <h1>Business</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- .jumbotron -->

    <div class="footer">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <p>By:</p>
            <p>For:</p>
        </div>
    </div><!-- .footer -->
```

Answer (score 0):

To address part of your issue, try putting the sections you would like to be side-by-side in the same div.row, then wrap a div.col-xx-x around each. For example:

```
<div class="nav">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <form class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Have Feedback?">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit Feedback</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure why you're not using the `<navbar>` class. It's there and ready to accomplish exactly what you're looking for. See this Bootply for example:

[Bootply - Navbar](http://www.bootply.com/fbRcIFjAeC)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="Have Feedback?" type="text">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit Feedback</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

There is a way to do it like you have it, but I'm not sure how to get the `<form>` to align perfectly with the `<nav>` class, since there's padding on it and moves it down from the top a bit. You may need some custom CSS to handle that.

[Bootply - Original](http://www.bootply.com/YFfa509yff)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <form class="form-horizontal">
        <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Have Feedback?" type="email">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit Feedback</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Give them both a look and see if either works for you.

Hope that helps!

Comment: navbar looks ok, but when I run the preview there's still misalignment. It's not a complete fluid line across from the form to the links.